# C# error when passing an instance of a derived class to a method

Tags: c#, delegates

I got this error

> CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from '`SerieSettings<SeriesLine>`' to '`SerieSettings<ISeries>`'

when I pass a SeriesLine type object as parameter, in this way

```
GraphLibrary().MultiTypeChart(settings => 
{
    settings.AddSeries((SerieSettings<SeriesLine>)(s =>
    {
        s.Name = "Temperatures";
    }));
});
```

to this method

```
public class GraphLibrary(){
    public GenericChartExtension MultiTypeChart(Action<GenericChartSettings> settings)
    {
        return new GenericChartExtension(settings);
    }
}
```

where *GenericChartExtension* and *BaseChartSettings* are

```
public sealed class GenericChartSettings : BaseChartSettings<ISeries>
{
}

public sealed class GenericChartExtension : BaseChartExtension<GenericChartSettings>
{
    public GenericChartExtension(Action<GenericChartSettings> applySettings) : base(applySettings) { }

    public override HtmlString Render()
    {
        return ChartSettings.Settings.Render();
    }
}
```

derived of *BaseChartSettings* and *BaseChartExtension*

```
public class BaseChartExtension<T>
{
    protected readonly T ChartSettings;

    public BaseChartExtension(Action<T> applySettings)
    {
        ChartSettings = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T));
        applySettings(ChartSettings);
    }
//....
public class BaseChartSettings<T> where T : ISeries
{
    public void AddSeries(SerieSettings<T> s) { Settings.AddSeries(s); }
```

*SerieSettings* is a delegate

```
public delegate void SerieSettings<V>(V s);
```

and *SeriesLine* is a derived of *ISeries*

```
public class SeriesLine: ISeries
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There are many, _many_ questions already on Stack Overflow regarding incorrect attempts to use generic types in a variant way. The marked duplicate is one such, but feel free to browse the others. Use keywords like "generic", "variance", "delegate", and "interface". The bottom line is that while `SeriesLine` is an `ISeries`, it does not necessarily follow from that that `SerieSettings<SeriesLine>` is a `SerieSettings<ISeries>`.